# border-radius working in all browsers, except IE9

Tags: html, css

On my [new site](http://blgz.co) border-radius doesnt seem to be working.

I can see the border curving, but the background doesn't.

Comment: you can use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) to post your code snippet.

Comment: I believe you are asking about div with Latest Stories title. can you try to remove #region-sidebar-second .block css rule and apply css provided in answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border-radius should work.

following works in IE 9

http://jsfiddle.net/Ec86p/3/

if supporting border-radius in IE7/IE8 is not a requirement then you should not include CSS3PIE as IE9 inclues support of border-radius css property.

**edit:**

i have updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr8vE/3/

and changed following:

```
#main-menu li.first{
border-left:1px solid #feb800;

border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;

border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;

padding-left:10px;
}
```

edit : # 2

as soon as i removed following from ( `#main-menu li` )

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fe9900', endColorstr='#ff7c00',GradientType=0 );
```

it started working. ( I tried it in IE 9, orange background seems to be curving similar to border )

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr8vE/15/

Comment: ^^^ I already knew that......Hence why I said it worked for every other div except one. I dont know why you guys answer without looking at the website. It's pretty obvious.

Comment: @George Milonas I believe you are asking about div with Latest Stories title. can you try to remove #region-sidebar-second .block css rule and apply simple css as provided in jsfiddle?

Comment: No i mentioned earlier its the orange menu bar.....I can literally see the border is curved, but the background is still there

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the solution you needed.

in your css apply this to the element that needs the rounded corner

```
#element{
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

download and search it in google **border-radius.htc** and save it in your image folder or anywhere you like it is an image with curve and it is use to fix IE problem.

I will post my css for my main menu that works for me with rounded border.

```
#main-nav {
width: 100%;
background: #ccc;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;
/* gradient */
background: #6a6a6a url(images/nav-bar-bg.png) repeat-x;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b9b9b9), to(#6a6a6a));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9,  #6a6a6a);
background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #b9b9b9, #6a6a6a);
/* rounded corner */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
/* box shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Please try this.

here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/vZaJX/

Hope it helped.

Comment: pls post your css of the main menu so that we can help you

Comment: I cant. Character limit/time limit per comment. Just use firebug to look it up

Comment: @GeorgeMilonas i added my css kindly try it

Comment: i'll post now the answer. please see my new answer i posted.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, it is not only the IE9, but also IE9 -.

you can either follow @Bert answer, or you can try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

the usage is just the same, but CSS3PIE provide more CSS3 features for IEs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is now the answer.

try to just edit the spacing of the words.

http://jsfiddle.net/ApYw4/

for IE 9 solution as i have told you
download this **border-radius.htc** and add to your css like this

```
#main-menu{
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
//all css
}
```

Dont hesitate to correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: I zoomed it in so you can see it better. As you can see, the border curves but the background doesn't!!!

Comment: as i told you in my post above follow the instruction to add the behavior: url(border-radius.htc); in your css. ill update it and follow. it works for me

Comment: Your original example worked. This one doesnt. I dont want to use the htc file.

Comment: look at this http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/ as i told you follow what i said.

Comment: Do me a favor....goto my site...blgz.co.....look at all those beautiful border-radius'......now look at the menu bar....you keep trying to fix my problem with a workaround that is not needed

Comment: but the work around is the only solution. as a web dev i have encountered this prob many times and this is the solution that fixed my problem. does it matter if you will use this technique?. lets asked other programmers here if they have solutions for this. but according to the solution given by the internet they only give this one.